# ping to server located on the same machine

Tags: 14.04, server, scripts, apache2, ping

My problem is that apache is sometimes completly freezing and can only be restarted by killing the proccess and starting the service again.

So I want to build a little workaround until I find a solution for that problem.
For this I want to make a script that checks if the website is reachable. If not then kill the process and start it again.

The apache server is on the same machine as the script so it's rather pointless to ping the IP or Domainname.

How can I do this?

Comment: `service apache2 status`?

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. While the Website is not reachable "service apache2 status" still says that the service is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an ICMP ping would never be of much use when testing to see if an HTTP server is running correctly.  Instead you need to make an HTTP request and verify that it is correct.  A popular technique is to use `curl` or `wget`, and check for text that you know should be in the reply.